# How to view password in ms outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, passwords

How can I view the password for a email account in Microsoft Outlook? I lost my password because of a virus attack.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that is possible without using a potentially malicious program.

You might be able to delete your account (not the pst) and then make a new account and import the pst if you care about keeping your mail.

Alternatively, you might be able to use an online password recovery process depending on what kind of email account you have.

Need more details about the situation to provide more useful solutions.